# Seeking Dominion Land Survey data (for Alberta, Saskatchewan, and Manitoba) to overlay in Google Earth?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, government

I am new to this type of work, and thought that it would not be at all difficult to find a repository of DLS data (as a .kmz, .shp, etc. file) depicting township, range, and section boundaries that I could load directly into Google Earth.

I managed to find this sort of data for Alberta, but the boundary detail is less than what I am looking for.